# Unable to "make" project even when cmake builds it successfully

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm working on a project where I need to use libsodium. I have successfully included it in my CMakeLists.txt file, which is shown immediately below:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(skip-list)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "/usr/local/include/sodium" "/usr/local/lib/**")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(Sodium REQUIRED)

add_executable(skip-list main.c)
target_include_directories(skip-list PRIVATE ${Sodium_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(skip-list PRIVATE ${Sodium_LIBS})
```

My directory tree structure looks like this:

```
-.vscode
  -settings.json
-build
  -everything cmake autogenerates
-src
  -cmake
    -all my cmake module files, i.e. FindSodium.cmake
  -main.c
  -CMakeLists.txt
```

My main.c is very simple as I'm just trying to get the library inclusion to work, but I've listed it below:

```
#include <sodium.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("here");
  if (sodium_init() < 0) {
    printf("error");
  } else {
    printf("%d\n", sodium_init());
  }
  printf("other side");
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

here1
other side

as one would expect

What works:

- When I run cmake ../src from the build directory, the build succeeds and a Makefile is generated.*
- If I run `clang -lsodium src/main.c -o main` and run it, my program runs beautifully.
- If I cmd+click on `#include <sodium.h>` I am successfully taken to the sodium.h file in my /usr/local/include directory and I am receiving intellisense, so I'm relatively certain the library itself is successfully installed on my machine.

What doesn't work:

- - when I run `make` inside my build directory, I get the following output:

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/skip-list.dir/main.c.o
/Users/anishsinha/Sandbox/skip-list/src/main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sodium.h' file not found
#include <sodium.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/skip-list.dir/main.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/skip-list.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Essentially what I'm getting is that the file <sodium.h> cannot be found, but I don't understand **why**, or how to fix it, because as far as I can see, sodium.h is being included properly when I compile from the command line, and cmake ../src is succeeding without errors.

If anyone could shed some light on this issue I'd be very grateful. If you answer or attempt to answer this question, thank you for your time.

Comment: Should not be `#include <sodium/sodium.h>`?

Comment: What is the full path to `sodium.h`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger /usr/local/include/sodium.h

Comment: @JohnBollinger I also tried it with /usr/local/include/libsodium/include/sodium.h which also exists

Comment: @273K No, <sodium/sodium.h> doesn't exist in /usr/local/include

Comment: What is in Sodium_INCLUDE_DIRS in CMakeCache.txt?

Comment: @273K it looks like: `sodium_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include`

Comment: Instead of manually adding the directory, which is incorrect according to you, you should instead be telling cmake to locate the library for you.

Comment: @sweenish that's great but how do I do that; is there a command I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that I was missing:

TL.DR I was using the wrong variables

In the Findsodium.cmake file, after it's run, it defines the following four variables:

```
#   sodium_FOUND
#   sodium_INCLUDE_DIR
#   sodium_LIBRARY_DEBUG
#   sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE
```

I was using sodium_INCLUDE_DIRS and sodium_LIBS, which was the convention for the OpenCV library which I was using before this. Once I switched to using sodium_INCLUDE_DIR and sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE, `make` worked successfully and the executable was successfully linked with the lib.

This is my final CMakeLists.txt which works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(skip-list)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(Sodium REQUIRED)

add_executable(skip-list main.c)
target_include_directories(skip-list PUBLIC ${sodium_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(skip-list PUBLIC ${sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE})

message("DIRS: ${sodium_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("LIBS: ${sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE}")
```

Comment: Glad to see you have fixed it. I just wanted to post an answer: *CMake variables are case sensitive. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables)* and so on...